# Need to extract values from string in Javascript between words and characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, string-matching

I will be receiving the following string format from an AJAX call: 
[link=https://www.w3schools.com text=here]

I need to extract the values after "link=" and the value after "text=" so, my ideal output would assign "https://www.w3schools.com" to a variable and then "here" to a variable as shown in the code below.  The values for "link=" and "text=" will change.

I've tried playing around with regex matching and using .split in Javascript, but I can't get the intended values just right.

```
var str = "[link=https://www.w3schools.com text=here]";
var link = str.match(/link=(.*)/)[1]; //gets the link but includes rest of string      
var linkText = str.match(/text=(.*)/)[1]; //gets "here" plus the closing bracket
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add **"\s"** and **"]"**  in your pattern, Try  this

```js
var str = "[link=https://www.w3schools.com text=here]";
var link = str.match(/link=(.*)\s/)[1]; //gets the link but includes rest of string      
var linkText = str.match(/text=(.*)]/)[1];

console.log(link);
console.log(linkText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```js
var str = "[link=https://www.w3schools.com text=here]";
var m, res=[], rx=/(?:^|[\s[])(link|text)=([^\][\s]*)/g;
while (m = rx.exec(str)) {
  console.log(m[1], "=", m[2]);
}
```

The regex is

```
/(?:^|[\s[])(link|text)=([^\][\s]*)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NXln7m/1).

**Details**

- `(?:^|[\s[])` - start of string or a whitespace or `[`
- `(link|text)` - Group 1: link or text words
- `=` - a `=` symbol
- `([^\][\s]*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than `[`, `]` and whitespace.